# How to make custom option in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my ajax

```
$.ajax(
{
   url: url,
   type: 'post',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {'id':'1','name':'user'},
   success: function(result) {}
});
```

So here is a basic setup of ajax but I want to add custom option `showLoader` in ajax. So how can I achieve it?

```
$.ajax(
{
   showLoader: true,
   url: url,
   type: 'post',
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {'id':'1','name':'user'},
   success: function(result) {}
});
```

`showLoader` will call when ajax requests start and end when ajax request stops.
in showLoader, there will be an image.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know how to make a custom option, but a work around, using         $(document).bind("ajaxSend", function () {
       //Show loader
        }).bind("ajaxComplete", function () {  
       //Hide loader
        });

Comment: No, i know this but i want a custom option.

Comment: You can make a Service class to send your ajax requests and inside this service class you start and stop ajaxEvents. That way in your parameters you can set showLoader option.

In the $.ajax function I think is not a better place to implement this.

Comment: @PauloTeixeira how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

The service class can be something like this

```
var Services = function () {
    this.showLoader = true;

    this.post = function( route, param, callback, showLoader = true, successMessage = '', failCallback = null, errorMessage = '' )
    {
        this.showLoader = showLoader;

        $.post( route, param )
            .success(function(data){
                if( successMessage.trim().length ) {
                    //notify successMessage
                }

                // if to have callback function call than
                if( null != callback ) {
                    callback(data);
                }
            })
            .fail(function(error, status, type){
                if( null != failCallback ) {
                    //notify error callback if this exists
                }
            });
    };
}
```

Then you implement the methods to execute the ajaxStart and stop inside the class and verify if the this.showLoader attribute is true or false before run.

So in your code you can send ajax request like:

```
var service = new Service();
service.post('/user/add', form.serialize(), function(){}, false, 'User added successfully!');
```

I recommend that you create the instance new Service() in a javascript in the begin of you page loader, to you not need to make a new instance every time that you need to send an ajax request.

This is one way, make you own implementation now!